# Letras fijas en un campo de mysql mediante php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo este código que me genera un número consecutivo cada vez que inserto un dato y me gustaría añadir las letras ESP fijas para que salga cada vez que añado un registro nuevo, el código es el siguiente:

```
 $codigo = (empty($consulta['num']) ? 1 : $consulta['num']+=1);
 echo 'El codigo actual es: '.$codigo;

 $consulta = mysqli_query($mysql,'INSERT INTO num_ficha (num) VALUES  ('.$codigo.')');
 if(!$consulta){die('Error');}
```

Comment: Me parece haberte respondido ayer en un comentario, sin embargo, no veo la pregunta, ¿la borraste?.

Answer (score 0):

Entonces lo unico que te falta es añadir precisamente el texto de ESP delante de codigo:

```
$codigo = (empty($consulta['num']) ? 1 : $consulta['num']+=1); echo 'El codigo actual es: '.$codigo;

$codigo='ESP'.$codigo; // te faltaria añadir esto.

$consulta = mysqli_query($mysql,'INSERT INTO num_ficha (num) VALUES ('.$codigo.')'); if(!$consulta){die('Error');}
```

Sin embargo, te sugiero que, cuando vayas a presentar el dato (seguro que en algun punto haces la consulta de SELECT), en ESE momento añadas el 'ESP' delante.

Esta sugerencia viene porque muy probablemente ese codigo sea de ESPAÑA, pero cuando tengas que internacionalizarlo, te sera mas conveniente relacionar la ficha con idioma/pais, y luego mostrar el codigo segun dicho pais. Si dicha ficha hay que cambiarle de codigo y lo tienes insertado en la tabla, tendrias que hacer operaciones de truncate sobre ese codigo.

En resumen,mejor que hagas algo tipo:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($mysql,'SELECT * FROM num_ficha'); 
if(!$consulta){die('Error');}

foreach($consulta as $fila) {
    echo 'ESP'.$fila->get('num');
}
```

Comment: añadir una columna `cod_pais` también sería una buena idea